# How to avoid quality loss when combining two images via CGBitmapContext in monotouch

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, core-graphics

I have two images. First (`avatar`) is 640x640, second (`like`) is 21x20.
When I'm trying to draw second on first, I get it, but with very low quality.
Here is the code:

```
var bounds = targeImageView.Bounds;
CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfo = CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast;
CGColorSpace colorSpaceInfo = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB ();
CGBitmapContext resultBitmap = new CGBitmapContext (IntPtr.Zero, (int)bounds.Width, (int)bounds.Height, 8, 4 * (int)bounds.Width, colorSpaceInfo, alphaInfo);
resultBitmap.DrawImage (bounds, avatar.CGImage);
var likeY = 0;
var likeX = 0;
var likeHeight = (float)Math.Floor (bounds.Height / 2);
var likeWidth = likeHeight;
resultBitmap.DrawImage (new RectangleF (likeX, likeY, likeWidth, likeHeight), like.CGImage);
targetImageView.Image = UIImage.FromImage (resultBitmap.ToImage ());
```

Here is the `avatar` picture on the same image view but without upper code, just `imageView.Image = avatar;`

[image: avatar]

Here is the same but after drawing.

[image]

Comment: The bitmap you attached are too small, i.e. I cannot see a quality difference between them. Could you enlarge them ? and/or describe the quality problem ? e.g. could it be it's not using retina (doubling-pixels instead) on the second one ?

Comment: Please, look closer, there IS a difference. I can see it even in that post without open it separately. And yes, retina considered, and that is iphone retina simulator.

Comment: @poupou: The difference is most obvious in the hair of the person in the left image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got better eyesight than me - at least at that small size. If it's a retina issue (I think so) then the following code should help you as it creates a context that will adjust itself to a retina (or not) display.

```
UIImage avatar = ...;
UIImage like = ...;
UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions (avatar.Size, false, 0);
using (CGContext ctx = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ()) {
    var rect = new RectangleF (Point.Empty, avatar.Size);
    avatar.Draw (rect);
    // coordinates are likely reversed (UIKit wrt CoreGraphics) you might have to fix them (untried)
    rect = new RectangleF (0, avatar.Height / 2, avatar.Width / 2, avatar.Height / 2);
    like.Draw (rect);

    targetImageView.Image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext ();
    UIGraphics.EndImageContext ();
    // dispose of avatar and like UIImage if not used anymore
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use PNGs they are lossless, and better quality than JPG or Bitmap.

   > NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
   >
   > UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
2. Allocate UIImageView with frame for placement using CGRectMake ().  You will be able to float the image anywhere you want.
3. Set the ImageView's Image with [ImageView setImage:...]
4. The Image will be rendered much cleaner and you will have full control over quality and placement.

I have used a 256 image compressed down to a 15px x 15px and it still held a very good shape.  In contrast I have also stretched images the other way around.

Comment: The questioner is compositing one image onto another; in what part of that is “Use PNGs” relevant? As for your other three steps, they appear to be a suggestion of how to *display an image*, but the questioner wants to *composite two images*. How does your suggestion perform the questioner's task? And, how is your suggestion different from the questioner's last line of code?

Comment: @Peter: My understanding of the question was to use the first image (avatar) and add sub-images (smiley face and cloud) as in the provided examples to "render" a unified appearance to the user.  My suggestion was to layer these and provide the user with a stacked image that could represent any number of configrations.  Such as badges, or clouds, etc that could be controlled ON/OFF, increment numbers, etc.  By actually ingraining the images, the new single image is stuck together.  You can always loop through the container UIView and snap an image of the all the sub-images for later.

Comment: @Peter Continued...What if the app wanted to use the layered "clouds" over the avatar to represent the user was "connected", there is much more flexibility in layering transparent high-quality pngs, than splicing them together at the bitmap level.  However, if the client app absolutely needs to ingrain the two images together as one, the you are correct then my responses does not support that effort.  If so, my apologies, perhaps it will help someone else.